# Representation formula for viscosity solutions of Hamilton-Jacobi equations

Tags: hamilton-jacobi-equation, viscosity-solutions

I am currently interested in viscosity solutions of the first-order Hamilton-Jacobi equations under Neumann boundary conditions.
For example, I consider the following initial boundary value problem:

$
\begin{cases}
u_t(x,t)+H(x,t,Du(x,t))=0 & \mathrm{in} \ \Omega \times (0,T), \\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}(x,t)=0 & \mathrm{in} \ \partial \Omega \times (0,T), \\
u(x,0)=u_0(x) & \mathrm{in} \ \Omega.
\end{cases}
$

I would like to know some representation formulas for the solution of this equation, but I do not know which references to consult.
If you know of any, please let me know.